# Pass DateTime parameter to multipart/form-data using HttpClient

Tags: c#, multipartform-data, dotnet-httpclient, .net-8.0

I have a form with a file and a datetime field.

```
public class SomeDto 
{
   IFormFile InputFile;
   DateTime ApplyingDateTime; 
}
```

I accept this form in controller

```
public async Task<ActionResult<Guid>> UploadFile([FromForm] SomeDto someDto)
```

It works when I call from swagger, but when I'm trying to call this method from HttpClient - it returns errors `BadRequest '"2024-01-19T00:00:00.000Z"' is not valid value for ApplyingDateTime`

My code, which uses HttpClient

```
using var content = new MultipartFormDataContent();

content.Add(new StreamContent(new MemoryStream(model.File)), "File", model.FileName);
content.Add(new StringContent(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(DateTime.UtcNow)), "ApplyingDateTime")

var httpResponse = await _httpClient.PostAsync(
  "my/url",
  content);

var result = await httpResponse.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Guid>(result);
```

I tried to use JsonContent instead of StringContent, DateTimeOffset instead of DateTime, but always got an error about extra quotes.

When I read content as string (`var contentStr = await content.ReadAsStringAsync();`) I really see additional quotes, which I don't in browser.

Could you please help me - what can I try to do?

Comment: "... but always got an error about extra quotes." - the quotes are probably from trying to convert to a JSON literal - try `new StringContent(DateTime.UtcNow.ToString("o"))` or similar instead